# Validate prop with function as input in redux form

Tags: redux, redux-form

i have a question about the validate prop.
Suppose we  (.....)
In the component we define this:

```
<Field>
 validate = {validate}
</Field>
```

Why cant we write validate={validate(value)} or why is not correct to write something like this: `validate={()=> validate(value)}`
Thanks!

Comment: Which redux-form version are you using?  Also, your code is not making much sense to me. Can you kindly provide more source code with more information to simplify your problem?

Comment: It's not a problem. It just a question i have for deeper understanding. I'm using the latest version

Comment: This answer illustrates a way, very well, how redux-form validation works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347035/redux-form-display-a-list-of-errors-on-top-of-a-page/39387754#39387754

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redux-form: display a list of errors on top of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347035/redux-form-display-a-list-of-errors-on-top-of-a-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `validate` prop on `Field` takes a function (or an array of functions) which should be used to validate the incoming field value. So you can't write `validate={ someCustomValidator(value) }`  unless the `someCustomValidator` function is a function you have defined that in turn returns a function.

Using `validate={()=> someCustomValidator(value)}` should work, but doesn't make much sense in the context of your example (where does `value` come from?). If you use `validate={(value)=> someCustomValidator(value)}` instead, that makes more sense, but this is problematic because this will create a new function each time the component with the `Field` re-renders. And according to the [documentation](https://redux-form.com/7.0.4/docs/api/field.md/#-code-validate-value-allvalues-props-name-gt-error-code-optional-):

> Note: if the validate prop changes the field will be re-registered.

which is probably not what you want to happen.

So, using

```js
// validation
const someCustomValidator = value => {
  // give error roughly half of the time
  return Math.random() < 0.5 ?
     undefined : // validation is ok
     'Validation failed'; // this will be available in meta.error
}

// somewhere else
<Field validate={someCustomValidator} />
```

is the correct way of using it. But note that `Field` doesn't internally know what to do to display potential validation errors. That you have to solve yourself. See https://redux-form.com/7.0.4/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/ for an example.